# Bundler reporting gems missing that aren't; Rails is invisible to Apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, passenger, bundler

### Background / setup

I've installed Ruby 1.9.3-p0 on a RedHat 6 system.

I ran `passenger-install-apache2-module` and inserted the snippet of config code into my httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11
PassengerRuby /usr/local/bin/ruby
```

I added a vhost config...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName contracker-rails3-test.mysite.com
    ServerAlias contracker-rails3-test

    DocumentRoot /opt/deployed_rails_apps/contracker/current/public

    <Directory /opt/deployed_rails_apps/contracker/current/public>
        AllowOverride all
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>

    RailsEnv production

</VirtualHost>
```

I deployed my app using Capistrano.

Then was (eventually) able to get Bundler to install the app's gems. So now Bundler is reporting all gems are installed and everything is fine.

## The main problem:

When I visit the app's URL in the browser I just get Apache's default welcome page. The app isn't producing any logging output (not even creating log files) so it seems like Rails isn't being reached at all.

### Things I checked

I verified that the vhost config is correct by putting an `index.html` file in the configured location. That file shows when I try the URL, so the vhost is fine.

I checked that the production DB is present and available.

The app works fine on my OS X development laptop.

I tried this experiment in the deployed app's root...

```
[em@web3 current]$ which ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby

[em@web3 current]$ which gem
/usr/local/bin/gem

[em@web3 current]$ gem list -l

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.2.1)
actionpack (3.2.1)
activemodel (3.2.1)
activerecord (3.2.1)
activeresource (3.2.1)
activesupport (3.2.1)

[...lots of gems...]

rails (3.2.1)

[...lots of gems...]

[em@web3 current]$ which rails
/usr/bin/which: no rails in (/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/emicha/bin)
```

Why is it not finding Rails?

Also tried this...

```
[em@web3 current]$ rails console
-bash: rails: command not found
```

### Bundler producing bizarre, nonsensical errors

I suspect it might have something to do with Bundler because I can't run any Rake tasks...

```
[em@web3 current]$ bundle exec rake -T
Could not find journey-1.0.2 in any of the sources
```

Also tried...

```
[em@web3 current]$ rake -T
Could not find journey-1.0.2 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Why would trying to run a Rake task cause Bundler to look for a gem called "journey" or any gem at all?

### And so...

Does anyone have an idea about any part of this?

Is there anything else I can check?

Comment: It can't find Rails because you must do `bundle exec rails`. Rake is trying to find journey because it's loading the Rails environment (journey is a part of Rails starting in 3.2).

Answer (score 1):

SELinux again.

It's preventing Apache from loading Passenger/Rails. I turned it off for the whole system and now the app is reachable. I have to figure out how to leave it on but get it to allow Rails.

However, Bundler is still exhibiting the same behavior with or without SELinux -- "Could not find xyz gem" that's actually installed.